# how does this model work in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps, django-managers

I found this code for a [blog post app](http://trespams.googlecode.com/svn/tags/trespams-1.0beta/blogmaker/comments/models.py) written using `Django` here:
I am confused with what this snippet of code does:
Please explain what the CommentManager class below do and how the parameters passed to it are assigned to some 'arbitrary keys'. The same `object` is used in `Comment` class below.
How is that used?

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):
    def comments_for_object(self, site_id, app_label, model, obj_id, comment_type='comment'):
        ''' Get a QuerySet of all public comments for the specified object. '''
        kwargs = {
            'site__id__exact': site_id,
            'content_type__app_label__exact': app_label,
            'content_type__model__exact': model,
            'object_id__exact': obj_id,
            'comment_type__exact': comment_type,
            'is_public__exact': True,
        }
        return self.filter(**kwargs)


class Comment(models.Model):
    ''' Data model for both comments and trackbacks '''
    objects = CommentManager()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.IntegerField(_('object ID'))
    comment = models.TextField(_('comment'), max_length=3000)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(_('is public'))
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField(_('ip address'))

    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    typeChoices = (
        ('comment', 'Comment'),
        ('trackback', 'Trackback'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

by default every Model in Django has a manager. The default one is a very simple - for example, when you write `Comment.objects.all()`, it's equivalent to a "SELECT * FROM ". You can also filter, for ex: Comment.objects.filter(is_public=True)
You can however write your own managers (CommentManager in this example) for custom queries.
Here the CommentManager is assigned to Comment: `objects=CommentManager()` which allows you to do request like this:

```
Comment.objects.comments_for_object(params)
```

Where params are (site_id, app_label, model, obj_id, comment_type). The code simply maps those params into the query.

Note that you can change the name by which you will access your Managers. You could write:

```
obj_comments=CommentManager()
```

then call:

```
Comment.obj_comments.comments_for_object(params)
```

Comment: why does `content_type__app_label` and `content_type__model` gets assisgned to passed int values? where does these come from?

Comment: Where they get assingned int values ? It doesn't seem like.